# Can't link my external css with my html page

Tags: html, css

[HTML source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPLEe.png)

[css sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrmaY.png)

I am following a course and can't progress until I figure this out, please help!

Comment: Consider posting your code as text from next time onwards since it's hard to type from an image :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're using a wrong value for the `type` attribute. Use either `type="text/css"` or remove the `type` altogether (since the default is `text/css`)